# combine duplicates, do not publish blanks, dplyr::distinct

Tags: r, dplyr

I trying to using dplyr distinct to combine rows, delete duplicates, and delete blanks as well.  Here is my data frame:

```
unique_id   school  subject  grade  sex
    1       great   Math      88    
    1       great   English   78    
    1       great   History   98    male
    2       spring  Math      65    
    2       spring  English   72    female
    2       spring  History   84
```

When I run (thank you Akrun):

```
(r2 <- df %>%
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(toString(unique(.)))))
```

I get:

```
unique_id   school  subject                     grade       sex
    1       great   Math, English, History      88,78,98     , male 
    2       spring  English, English, History   65,72,84     , female
```

I don't want blanks to be included or commas in the last variable, sex.  Instead, I'd like it to look as follows:

```
unique_id   school  subject                     grade       sex
    1       great   Math, English, History      88,78,98     male   
    2       spring  English, English, History   65,72,84     female
```

Any tried adding NA on the import, then removing it after condensing and that didn't work.  Any ideas how to condense rows, but only keep the value in the row and ignore blanks?  Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want commas, why are you using `toString`?

Comment: that's what was recommended to me.  What would you recommend I replace it with?

Comment: Replace the empty string in the sex column with the same gender for each unique_id and then it will work.

Comment: Use `NA`s, they're there for a reason.

Comment: I tend to agree re: NAs, but in this instance, with this data frame, they're useless.

Comment: I disagree, this question would have solved it self if you'd used them.

Comment: @Axeman, if unique_id 1 represents one student, explain to me why I would want an outcome of: NA, male or NA, female, etc.? The student is either male or female, and every single unique_id will list it at least once.  In other words, that variable is never left empty(NA).  For binary outcomes, I don't see the value of NAs, as long as the outcome is listed at least once.

Comment: also, if you want to publish the contents of the observation, it will publish NA and others.  In the case of my example, it I were to publish the sex category, it would show as: NA, male.  That would look ridiculous.  And what if you want to split the variable with multiple observations into columns, you're going to get a column for NA.

Comment: Group properly, and subset out the values you don't want: `df %>% group_by(unique_id, school) %>% summarise_all(funs(toString(.[nchar(.) > 0])))` Or better, just use `NA`s so you can use `na.omit`.

Comment: @alistaire, I tried running your code, but all the NAs still remain.

Comment: What `NA`s? The data in the question just has empty strings, not `NA`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the reason that you are having problems is that you are using empty strings when you should be using NAs. This is what I would assume is the idiomatic code.

```
df <- data.frame(unique_id = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),
                school = c(rep('great',3),rep('spring',3)),
                           subject = rep(c("Math", "English", "History"),2),
                           grade = c(88,78,98,65,72,84),
                           sex = c(NA,NA, "male", NA, "female", NA))

r2 <- df %>%
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(toString(unique(.))))
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  unique_id school                subject      grade        sex
      <dbl>  <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1         1  great Math, English, History 88, 78, 98   NA, male
2         2 spring Math, English, History 65, 72, 84 NA, female
```

You can always

```
 r2$sex <- sapply(stringr::str_split(r2$sex, ", "),"[",2)
```

afterwards if you **really** want to remove those NAs, but I see them as informative.

You can write your own function to supply to `summarize_each`, which will allow you to take care of NAs in any column. Note, that you only need to do this because `unique`, rightfully so, does not have an `na.rm` argument.

```
rm_na_unique <- function(vec){
  unique(vec[!is.na(vec)])
}

r2 <- df %>%
       group_by(unique_id) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(toString(rm_na_unique(.))))
```

Gives you the same result

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  unique_id school                subject      grade    sex
      <dbl>  <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>
1         1  great Math, English, History 88, 78, 98   male
2         2 spring Math, English, History 65, 72, 84 female
```

Comment: thanks @shayaa.  I don't want NAs in the cell.  I'd like to ignore blanks, and only including values.  See desired end result in the top.  Thank you.

Comment: works perfectly, THANK YOU @shayaa.  Quick question, can you remove all NAs from the data frame?  There are >200+ observations and 30 variables in this particular data frame.  That would be pretty time consuming , to write this for each variable.  That's why I was hoping I could remove spaces and blanks when combining rows.  Thanks again.

Comment: Edited again. But, **seriously** consider using NAs in this instance. They are not useless. They tell you that you do not have information about the all three students in each school.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the `sex` column so that there will be no empty strings in it and then your solution will work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(unique_id) %>% mutate(sex = unique(sex[sex != ""])) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(toString(unique(.))))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
# 
#   unique_id school                subject      grade    sex
#       <chr>  <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>
# 1         1  great Math, English, History 88, 78, 98   male
# 2         2 spring Math, English, History 65, 72, 84 female
```