# collapse rows, keep uniques, remove dups, separate by semicolon

Tags: r

Very simple question, but I've tried a bunch of variations but cannot get my data frame to make this small change.

Starting data frame:

```
l = c("a", "b", "", "c","d") 
c = c("green", "blue", "black","red","") 
n = c(1,1,1,2,2) 
df = data.frame(n,c,l)
```

Desired output:

```
l = c("a;b","c;d") 
c = c("green;blue;black","red") 
n = c(1,2) 
dff = data.frame(n,c,l)
```

A very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556488/combine-duplicates-do-not-publish-blanks-dplyrdistinct), and this code works perfectly, I just can't get it to separate by semicolon.

Here is the code:

```
#Combine Rows, delete dups, keep uniques, remove NAs
library(dplyr)
rm_na_unique <- function(vec){
  unique(vec[!is.na(vec)])
}

df <- df %>%
  group_by(n) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(toString(rm_na_unique(.))))
```

I tried putting in the line of code below in various places, but it doesn't seem to work.  Sorry for the simple question, but as you can I did try to figure this out.  Sometimes these little issues are the most difficult to figure out when you don't have a command of syntax yet.  Thank you.

```
(paste(., collapse = ";")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have blanks (`""`) instead of `NA`

```
df %>%
    group_by(n) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(paste(.[nzchar(as.character(.))], collapse=";")))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
#     n                c     l
#  <dbl>            <chr> <chr>
#1     1 green;blue;black   a;b
#2     2              red   c;d
```

Comment: thanks @akrun! And if I only wanted unique values in the other variables (c, l), after the collapse, would I just add `unique` in the summarise_each line of code?

Comment: In  that case just wrap `unique` i.e. `summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.[nzchar(as.character(.))]), collapse=";")))`

Comment: Thanks @ akrun!  Did you invent R?  ha. I see your name all over the answers on here.  Thanks again.

Comment: @BlueDevilPride  No problem.  No, i didn't invent R :-)  Just a regular user.